# Changing Emoji Shortcut

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, emoji

I'm using El Capitan and I want to change emoji shortcut which is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. I want to change it to two buttons? Is it possible?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This will work everywhere that Emoji & Symbols has a menu item...

- System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts
- Click 'All Applications'
  <sub>(hidden in the picture)</sub>
- Click +
- Type Emoji & Symbols in the first box
- Type your replacement trigger in the second
- Click Add

<sup>As noted in comments, Cmd/Space is usually used for Spotlight. I chose this almost at random & discarded after the picture was taken.</sup>

[image]

Comment: ⌘Space is however used by Spotlight (and also to switch keyboard layouts priori to El Capitan)

Comment: For sure - I just picked something almost at random & discarded it after I'd taken the shot.

Comment: In spanish the Menu Title is: "Emojis y símbolos"

Comment: Big Sur 11.1 Beta (20C5048k) ... have needed this again.. so still relevant in Dec 2020.

Comment: The native shortcut for emojis is cmd+control+space.
But, sometimes, it doesn't work well anymore, I can't figure out why. Has to do with focus or something.

Comment: This method seem to work, but it's very flaky. You basically never know if shortcut will work or not. For me it is so unstable that I gave up on this approach

Comment: Works great for me on MacOS 13.6. I used `ctrl-opt-cmd-space` to avoid conflicts with other shortcuts.

Comment: Confirmed this works in MacOS 14.x Sonoma where Emoji keyboard default has been changed to use a Fn key. If you're like me using a mechanical keyboard with no Fn key, this is the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, on macOS 13.6, I bound <kbd>fn</kbd> to display the emoji picker:

In **Keyboard**, there's a setting called **Press <kbd>fn</kbd> to** where you can choose among others **Show Emoji & Symbols**.

It works well for me on the MacBook itself, although the drawback is that I also have an external keyboard that doesn't have the <kbd>fn</kbd>. For that case, I also bound another shortcut, as per Tetsujin's answer.

[image: Screenshot of the Keyboard settings in macOS 13.6 with the 'Press fn key to' option highlighted]

Answer (score 1):

As a quick add-on to Tetsujin’s great answer, you could use [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to remap it to a single key if you wished.

Currently I’ve reassigned Caps Lock to showing the emoji picker.

Comment: Hey @Simon, I was looking to do the same. Can you share how you did it?

Comment: @Farzad As this is some time ago, I can’t remember exactly how I did it with Karabiner, since I’m not using that method anymore. But I’m pretty sure you could make a ‘complex modification’ (with some help from Google) so that one keypress triggers several others. Right now I’m using the fn key to trigger the emoji menu. That can be achieved under Keyboard in System Preferences. Look for the little globe icon.